# C++ type_traits for is static variable

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits

Is there any way in C++11 to know if this is "const static" variable or no? 
Linked to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391973/undefined-reference-to-static-const-int) 
I need this to modify this function:

```
template<typename T>
std::string to_string1(const T& value)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << value;
    return oss.str();
}
```

Live demo http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef91dff7d99aab29

If I have some "const int" variable compiler say "undefined reference". 
To avoid this I want to modify function like this (without & for this case):

```
template <typename T>
std::stringtost(
    typename std::conditional< 
        std::is_static<T>::value , 
        const T, 
        const T&
    >::type 
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << value;
        return oss.str();
){
```

So I'll have 2 functions - one for static const (with T value parameter), ant second for all other (with T& parameter)

Comment: Check your second code example. And maybe it would be easier to solve the problem with undefined reference?

Comment: I think you're just missing a static variable definition. This seems like a major XY problem.

Comment: Look at this live demo http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef91dff7d99aab29

Comment: @tower120, Exactly, it's missing definitions for the static variables. You still need the `const int A::F;` etc.

Comment: I mean your second code sample is syntactically incorrect. And I subscribe to the @chris words about solving a problem of declared but undefined static variable.

Comment: The error happens at the reference binding (to `value` parameter) when you call the function. Doing magic inside the function won't help.

Comment: Second example is what I whant to get. It's not work, std::is_static even not exists. I want you to tell me what to do, so it work, or how to avoid this problem.

Comment: I mean only syntax, not semantics.

Comment: @jrok - so, what I have to do? I want to make 2 functions one T (for const static) and another T&

Comment: Add strings `constexpr float A::SM;` and `const int A::F;` after `struct A` declaration.

Comment: @Constructor - Works!!! But why?

Comment: In-class initialization of static variables is not definition. You should still define them outside of a class declaration.

Comment: @Constructor - But why it work when I pass them without reference?

Comment: Without reference compiler does not use addresses of your static variables, only values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined reference to static class member](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272900/undefined-reference-to-static-class-member)