# Cuda C++ template undefined reference Compilation issue while porting a visual studio project to linux

Tags: c++11, templates, makefile, cuda, g++

I am trying to compile the following code ([[cuShiftOr]](http://www-hagi.ist.osaka-u.ac.jp/research/code/cuShiftOr.20160623.zip)) to a linux box. Original code is running on Visual Studio 2013 in Windows.

My strategy is to compile all .cu files like below:

```
nvcc -std=c++11 -Icpp11-range -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2013 -maxrregcount=0 --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DNDEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -I$HOME/cuShiftOr/CuShiftOr -I$HOME/cuShiftOr/CuShiftOrBenchmark -I$HOME/cuShiftOr/tinyformat -Xcompiler "-fPIC -fexceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fpermissive" -ccbin=/opt/cray/pe/craype/2.5.10/bin/CC -c CuShiftOr/device/hybrid.cu -o objs/CuShiftOr/device/hybrid.cu.o
```

Likewise for the rest.
At the final stage link everything together by running:

```
nvcc -std=c++11 -Icpp11-range -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2013 -maxrregcount=0 --machine 64 -cudart static -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DNDEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -I$HOME/cuShiftOr/CuShiftOr -I$HOME/cuShiftOr/CuShiftOrBenchmark -I$HOME/cuShiftOr/tinyformat -Xcompiler "-fPIC -std=c++11 -Icpp11-range -fexceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fpermissive -Wnon-template-friend" -ccbin=/opt/cray/pe/craype/2.5.10/bin/CC -o CuShiftOrBenchmark.a   objs/CuShiftOr/device/hybrid.cu.o  objs/CuShiftOr/util/op.cu.o  objs/CuShiftOr/device/segment.cu.o  objs/CuShiftOr/host.cu.o  objs/CuShiftOr/util/timer.cu.o  objs/CuShiftOr/util/file.cu.o  objs/CuShiftOr/util/generator.cu.o  objs/CuShiftOrBenchmark/kernel.cu.o -lm
```

However that leads me this undefined reference issue:

```
objs/CuShiftOrBenchmark/kernel.cu.o: In function `void run_benchmark<unsigned int>(std::ostream&, cushiftor::device::Handler<unsigned int>*, long, unsigned int, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
tmpxft_00003ea2_00000000-4_kernel.cudafe1.cpp:(.text._Z13run_benchmarkIjEvRSoPN9cushiftor6device7HandlerIT_EEljiNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_Z13run_benchmarkIjEvRSoPN9cushiftor6device7HandlerIT_EEljiNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x203): undefined reference to `cushiftor::util::op::bit<unsigned int>::size'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

inside op.cuh it is defined as:

```
template<typename type>
    struct bit {
            static const int size = sizeof(type) * 8;
    };
template<typename word>
__host__ __device__ __forceinline__ word ones(int m) {
        return ~word(0) >> (bit<word>::size - m);
}
```

and then on kernel.cu we have:

```
#include "util/op.cuh"
using cushiftor::util::op::bit;
using cushiftor::util::op::bytepack;
using cushiftor::util::op::div_up;
using cushiftor::util::op::round_up;
using cushiftor::util::op::shuffle_up;
```

Further more compiling with Visual Studio 2013 (which works since the project was made on that) shows some instantiations that I am not sure if g++ is doing e.g:

```
2>C:/Users/A/Desktop/cuShiftOr/CuShiftOrBenchmark/kernel.cu(209): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'int64_t' to 'cushiftor::env::datasize_t', possible loss of data
2>          C:/Users/A/Desktop/cuShiftOr/CuShiftOrBenchmark/kernel.cu(230) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void benchmark_with_file<word>(cushiftor::device::Handler<word> *)' being compiled
2>          with
2>          [
2>              word=unsigned int
2>          ]
2>C:/Users/A/Desktop/cuShiftOr/CuShiftOrBenchmark/kernel.cu(86): warning C4018: '<=' : signed/unsigned mismatch
2>          C:/Users/A/Desktop/cuShiftOr/CuShiftOrBenchmark/kernel.cu(132) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void run_benchmark<word>(std::ostream &,cushiftor::device::Handler<word> *,int64_t,cushiftor::env::datasize_t,int,std::string)' being compiled
2>          with
2>          [
2>              word=unsigned int
2>          ]
```

Now my C++11 template knowledge is very limited but I did try to instantiate also inside the kernel.cu by adding:

```
template class cushiftor::util::op::bit<unsigned int>;
```

However to no avail... Any tips are very welcomed!

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: question adapted let me know if you need more info!

Comment: by adding `template <typename T> const int bit<T>::size;` after the line that is `const int TRY = 10;` in `kernel.cu`, I was able to get the code to compile using `nvcc -arch=sm_61 -std=c++11 -o test -ICuShiftOr -ICuShiftOr/device -ICuShiftOr/util -Itinyformat CuShiftOrBenchmark/*.cu CuShiftOr/*.cu CuShiftOr/util/*.cu CuShiftOr/device/*.cu`.  I don't have a full explanation (or I would post it as an answer) but I believe it relates to the difference between declaration and definition of a static member of a templated class/struct.

Comment: Indeed Robert that seems to work, I have also found out a hack around it basically you replace 
bit<word>::size
with
sizeof(word) * 8

I am not sure either why this template struct is not getting passed along, I suspected that the compiler optimize it out but that wasn't the case. Thank you very much for your input!

Comment: actually the problem is related to the use of the object with the system in `tinyformat.h`.  I have created a non-CUDA minimal reproducer, so this is not specific to CUDA or `nvcc`.  I can reproduce the problem with `g++` 4.8.5

Comment: The `format` function in `tinyformat.h` is taking a varargs reference parameter, which includes this static member, and it seems to be stepping into [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391973/undefined-reference-to-static-const-int).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this question is essentially a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391973/undefined-reference-to-static-const-int).  However simply marking it as such with no explanation may be a bit obscure.  Therefore I'm going to provide a CW answer in the hopes that someone may improve it or correct me if I am wrong.

A possible [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) derived from the code is as follows (note that I'm converting to using `g++` directly rather than `nvcc`, as the manifestation and workarounds are the same):

```
$ cat test.cpp
#include <iostream>

namespace cushiftor {
namespace util {
namespace op {

template<typename type>
struct bit {
        static const int size = sizeof(type) * 8;
};

}
}
}

#ifdef FIX2
void f(const int data){
#else
void f(const int &data){
#endif
  std::cout << "size of type in bits is: " <<  data << std::endl;
}

using cushiftor::util::op::bit;

#ifdef FIX1
template <typename T> const int bit<T>::size;
#endif

template<typename word>
void run_benchmark() {
  f(bit<word>::size);
}

int main(){

  run_benchmark<unsigned>();
}
$ g++ -o test test.cpp
/tmp/ccCW51e3.o: In function `void run_benchmark<unsigned int>()':
test.cpp:(.text._Z13run_benchmarkIjEvv[_Z13run_benchmarkIjEvv]+0x5): undefined reference to `cushiftor::util::op::bit<unsigned int>::size'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
$ g++ -DFIX1 -o test test.cpp
$ g++ -DFIX2 -o test test.cpp
$
```

This MCVE was created based on inspection of relevant code in `kernel.cu`, `tinyformat.h`, and `op.cuh`, in [the original cuShiftOr project](http://www-hagi.ist.osaka-u.ac.jp/research/code/cuShiftOr.20160623.zip) (and [paper](http://hgpu.org/?p=16918)).

We see that if we compile the code as-is, it generates a similar error to that reported in the question.

Compiling with `-DFIX2` demonstrates that taking the item in question (`bit::size`) as a *reference* argument is essential to witnessing of the issue.

Compiling with `-DFIX1` eliminates the issue, and I believe is the correct approach in this case.

The explanation for this issue seems to be that the compiler may treat the `static const` member as a compile-time constant, unless it is "used" in the code.  ("Used" has a special language-specific meaning here.) If it is "used" in the code, then the compiler must be able to take the address of it (sensible in the case of a reference parameter) and to take the address of it, the class/struct definition is not sufficient.  (It is apparently only a *declaration* even though it appears in the class/struct *definition*.   The declaration is sufficient for usage equivalently to a compile-time constant, but is not sufficient for the case where we wish to take the address of it.)

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391973/undefined-reference-to-static-const-int):

> If a static data member is of const integral or const enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a constant-initializer which shall be an integral constant expression (5.19) In that case, the member can appear in integral constant expressions. **The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is used in the program**

I believe the `FIX1` code modification satisfies the bolded requirement above.

With the above preamble, I believe it is valid to mark this as a duplicate.

With respect to the behavior of the original project on windows, I would conjecture that compilers may have leeway in enforcement of this, and may in fact provide referenceable member symbols even when the program does not explicitly define them.